# System.CalloutException: For input string: "password@app.fluidsurveys.com"

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to access the fluid survey API in Sales force. I use the following code but it responds with an error.

The code for controller class is:

```
public class fluidSurvey{
    public String tst{set;get;}
    public String result{get;set;}

    public PageReference chk() {

        //if (!ApexPages.hasMessages())
            result=getData();

        return null;
    }
 public String getData()
   {
       HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
       Http http = new Http();
       req.setMethod('GET');
       String url = 'https://username:password@app.fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/surveys/';
       req.setEndpoint(url);
       HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
       String json =  res.getBody().replace('\n','');
       tst = json;
        try {
            JSONObject j = new JSONObject( json );
            return parseJson(j);
        } catch (JSONObject.JSONException e) {
            return 'Error parsing JSON response from Google: '+e;
        }

   }

   public String parseJson(JSONObject resp){
       String detail =resp.getString('total');

       return detail;
   }
}
```

and the code for apex page is:

```
<apex:page controller="fluidSurvey">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
   <h1>Fluid Survey</h1>
   <apex:form >
       <apex:outputText value="{!tst}"></apex:outputText>
      <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!chk}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

but when I click the submit button it create the following error:

```
System.CalloutException: For input string: "password@app.fluidsurveys.com"
Error is in expression '{!chk}' in component <apex:page> in page fluid-page
```

Comment: Have you added the "fluidsurveys.com" to the list of Remote Sites (endpoints that code is allowed to send messages to)? You can find this in Setup search.

Comment: Yes i have created a Remote site for it

Comment: Can you please post a debug output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the Authorization header.

Try the following code:

```
public String getData()
{
    HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    String authString = 'username:password';
    String url = 'https://app.fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/surveys/';
    req.setEndpoint(url);

    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(authString)));

    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    String json =  res.getBody().replace('\n','');

    try {
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject( json );
        return parseJson(j);
    } catch (JSONObject.JSONException e) {
        return 'Error parsing JSON response from Google: '+e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your response buddy .. I have Coded it the same way as you mentioned and it works for me....

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use the username:password@host format to pass authenticate info in the URL for Callouts, you have to explicitly set an Authentication HTTP header in your request to pass the credentials instead. (exactly how you do this will depend on what authentication types the server supports)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and it may be a possible reason because fluidsurvey works on oAuth 2.0, but I have Checked that URL in browser and it working fine, it was generating the json output. so thats why i try it this way